# How to deal with special characters when using CRUD operations in Express routes via fetch()?

Tags: javascript, express, crud

I have a basic CRUD system setup, however the system fails when special characters are used.

For example, here is my route for a delete request:

```
// DELETE OPERATIONS
router.route('/delete/:id').delete((req, res) => {
  const title = req.params.id;
  // console.log('DEBUG: aricles.js: server receiving title: ', title)
  DBM.deleteArticle(title).then(() => {
    console.log('DEBUG: article deleted: ', title);
  }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log('articles/delete error', err);
  });
  res.end();
});
```

My unique ID for an entry is a string which is the title of the article.  However if the string ends with a `?` which is a special character it disappears by the time it gets to the server.

The client sends the delete request as follows:

```
const options = { 
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
  method: 'DELETE', 
  body: JSON.stringify(this.props.data)
};

this.debug && console.log('cleint sending title: ', title);

fetch("/articles/delete/" + title, options )
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('response', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('delete clicked error', error);
  });
```

I imagine other special characters in the URL would cause issues as well such as `#` and `:`, etc.

Comment: You should require the `title` to be encoded or use ids for that, for example, save the I’d to be used internally, and create a GUID to be used publicly

Comment: `fetch('/articles/delete/' + encodeURIComponent(title), ...`